# C++ Template Ambiguity

Tags: c++, templates, grammar

A friend and I were discussing C++ templates. He asked me what this should do:

```
#include <iostream>

template <bool>
struct A {
    A(bool) { std::cout << "bool\n"; }
    A(void*) { std::cout << "void*\n"; }
};

int main() {
    A<true> *d = 0;
    const int b = 2;
    const int c = 1;
    new A< b > (c) > (d);
}
```

The last line in main has two reasonable parses. Is 'b' the template argument or is `b > (c)` the template argument?

Although, it is trivial to compile this, and see what we get, we were wondering what resolves the ambiguity?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK it would be compiled as `new A<b>(c) > d`. This is the only reasonable way to parse it IMHO. If the parser can't assume under normal circumstances a > end a template argument, that would result it much more ambiguity. If you want it the other way, you should have written:

```
new A<(b > c)>(d);
```

Answer (score 6):

As stated by Leon & Lee, 14.2/3 (C++ '03) explicitly defines this behaviour.

C++ '0x adds to the fun with a similar rule applying to `>>`.  The basic concept, is that when parsing a template-argument-list a non nested `>>` will be treated as two distinct `>` `>` tokens and not the right shift operator:

```
template <bool>
struct A {
  A(bool);
  A(void*);
};

template <typename T>
class C
{
public:
  C (int);
};

int main() {
    A<true> *d = 0;
    const int b = 2;
    const int c = 1;
    new C <A< b  >>  (c) > (d); // #1
    new C <A< b > >  (c) > (d); // #2
}
```

'#1' and '#2' are equivalent in the above.

This of course fixes that annoyance with having to add spaces in nested specializations:

```
C<A<false>> c;  // Parse error in C++ '98, '03 due to "right shift operator"
```

Comment: I've heard about this before.  Some compilers have jumped the gun by allowing `x<y<z>>` anyway.  But I'm just wondering: is it actually defined in terms of context-sensitive lexing, or by a grammar rule like TemplateId '<' TemplateId '<' TemplateArgument '>>' given in its own right?

Comment: @Stewart: It's the former (context-sensitive lexing).  To summarise, 14.2/3 says that while parsing a template-argument-list the first non-nested >> is treated as two separate > tokens.  You can read the actual paper for more info:  http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1757.html

Answer (score 3):

The C++ standard defines that if for a template name followed by a `<`, the `<` is always the beginning of the template argument list and the first non-nested `>` is taken as the end of the template argument list.

If you intended that the result of the `>` operator be the template argument, then you'd need to enclose the expression in parentheses. You don't need parentheses if the argument was part of a `static_cast<>` or another template expression.

Answer (score 0):

The greediness of the lexer is probably the determining factor in the absence of parentheses to make it explicit.  I'd guess that the lexer isn't greedy.

Comment: But isn't the lexing completely unambiguous?

Comment: It will error out on ambiguity, so yes.  Being greedy or non-greedy doesn't make you ambiguous.  Greediness is actually a way to resolve ambiguity.  You also get into the interaction between the lexer and the parser in this case, so maybe it's the parser that's not greedy.

Comment: The grammar may be ambiguous, but the lexer is absolutely not. The spacing makes the lexer completely well defined.

Comment: I agree with you.  I never said the lexer is ambiguous.