# What are the main differences between C++, D and C++0x?

Tags: c++, c++11, d

We all encounter and hear them more often lately and i'd like some good comparison between them right here on stackoverflow. Links, references and articles are fine also.

Comment: i am looking for screened and exp. backed answers, not the usual google search.

Comment: I removed the C tag as the question doesn't concern C in any way.

Comment: Your question is **way** too big.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: I find it funny how such a big question initiated so small of a discussion. :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My experience is mostly that C++0x tweaks certain aspects of C++, but essentially, it's the same language, just cleaner and somewhat more flexible. However, there are plenty of the major problems left in C++0x, like #include, and the automatic type deduction code for regular functions doesn't go far enough by quite some way. I like C++0x, it's a great improvement, but it's a *small* step in the right direction.

D, I found to be, well. I dunno. I didn't like D. I felt that it didn't fix the problems that *needed* fixing in C++, and pretty much went it's own way. I mean, there's nothing wrong with a language being whatever it wants to be, but it didn't feel to me like D genuinely evolved on C++, it's just a C++/C# hybrid and is only as much an evolution as C# is. For example, it has the same single-root object hierarchy, enforced GC, etc. It felt to me that D could be C# with some features like generics and RTCG just moved to compile-time instead of run-time.

C++0x doesn't go far enough and D wandered way off to the side into a field where C# and Java already exist. I'm definitely still in the market for something else as a C++ successor.

Comment: The last paragraph certainly describes in few well chosen words what i've heard from most that have played with both C++0x and D, when asked to compare them with C++. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: C++ works; D doesn't. It's as simple as that. By "works" I mean C++ proved itself, and D didn't. C++ caught on, D didn't. Airplanes, spacecrafts, submarines, nuclear-plants work on C++ without a single explosion. I want to see that happening with garbage collection and "a language for the masses"!

Comment: "I felt that it didn't fix the problems that needed fixing in C++" --> Do you mind sharing some examples? :)

Comment: The fundamental misconception of the "let's fix C++" crusaders is that there's something to fix. People think C++ is hard and this is something to fix. The truth is that **programming** is hard. The trick is in creating a language which promotes correct code, and C++ *excels* at that like almost no other language. The reason, I think, is because of its strong guarantees, because of its efficiency and because of flexibility in paradigms. Only its ties to C are questionable as to wether they make C++ more popular or less popular.

Comment: @Lambert: How about multiple inheritance? I guess strictly speaking, it doesn't need fixing, but D sure doesn't have it. How about reflection- either static or dynamic? Or a genuinely extended Standard library- covering things like GUIs, or at least, an actual single library that is Standard? Compared to the *massive* libraries available to C#. Does D have a Standard ABI and name mangling?

Comment: @DeadMG: Multiple inheritance is the *only* feature I've seen that it doesn't have. (Whether that's a good or bad thing is another matter... it has interfaces at least.) For the rest of those, though:
Yes, it has static reflection (go search for "traits").
Yes, there are the DFL and GtkD libraries for GUI, although neither is standard in the sense that it's part of the standard framework.
And Yes, it does have a standard ABI and name mangling; just look at the links, e.g.: http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/abi.html

Comment: @wilhelmtell: "People think C++ is hard and this is something to fix."

Yes, it is hard, and yes, it needs fixing. C++ templates frequently use side-effects -- rather than code itself -- to convey what they mean. Read this article to see what I mean, I can't explain it here: http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/templates-revisited.html
(The main quote: "Template metaprogramming in C++ often seems to be relying on side effects rather than being able to expressly code what is desired.")

Comment: @wilhelmtell: Never mind the fact that something simple like `map<string, map<int, string>> m;` doesn't even compile on C++ (although C++0x tried to fix that but introduced much more horrific syntax for lots of other things).
Take a look at this page and look for "context-free grammar": http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/overview.html
With separate semantic and syntax analysis stages, D code becomes virtually unambiguous and much more readable and cleaner than C++.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: I think you have it wrong, the fundamental problem of C++ is that that people think it *can be fixed*. It can't: the time to fix it was before the first Standard was released. The disappointment of D is that it didn't do enough to bother.

Comment: @wilhemltell: Sorry to put three messages here, but also take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52506/c-template-ambiguity

Comment: @Yttril: +1... Just curious, do you mean the language (specifications) wasn't good enough, or the implementation (compiler)? If it's the former, I'm curious to know why? :) @Wilhelmtell: Another example of ambiguous C++ code: Can you tell what this is supposed to do? `y = (T)-1;`

Comment: @lambert: template meta programming by specification proves C++ is screwed. Go look at language with real polymorphism like Haskell or Ocaml. The core problems are that the underlying type system of C++ is crud, and dependent name lookup which is primarily an artefact of trying to support class methods. It's too late for C++ for these things to be removed.

Comment: @Yttril: Thanks for the comment! However, I was referring to what you meant regarding D, not C++... unless you'd say that template metaprogramming is also a problem in D? (If so, why?)

Comment: @Lambert @Yttrill templates are an example of a C++ feature use that was broaden well beyond what it was intended for. Not in a bad way, mind you. It's just that people stretched the templates' capacity to its limit. For example, using templates with side-effects for policies. There's nothing wrong with C++ here; on the contrary. It just means that there's a feature missing. C++0x tried to bring in concepts, but alas, the proposal wasn't ready and failed. Maybe next time. Still: C++ has the **strongest**, **best** templates in the **world**. And you want to "fix that"?

Comment: @wilhelmtell: Strongest? Best? In what way? (Support please?) Could you come up with a useful example that you can't do in D?

Comment: @Lambert @Yttrill I'm not saying the templates can't be improved. In particular, I'd love to see better template error messages from the compiler. But that's because there's a feature missing if we want to keep using templates for what we use them for. I mean, we use templates for policies in modern code, and that's where the errors fail. Not in what templates where introduced for, which was for generalizing code.

Comment: Oh I wasn't referring to the error messages, that's the least of my problems when using templates. Just look at the syntax ambiguities! How is that "the strongest" and "best" in the world?! If you could provide examples, that would be very nice and I would be very interested. :)

Comment: @Lambert obviously this is a matter of opinion. But they're compile-time, which means they're as fast as it gets. They support types as well as primitives and templates, which means they're flexible. They support specialization, which means they construct a language in and of themselves, turing-complete and all. Now find me another language that does anything approaching this power and I'll take back my words.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: I don't know if you know, but D templates are *also* compile-time, and I'd say much more flexible than C++'s. Furthermore, they can be specialized just as well as in C++, *without* the ambiguities and *with* the clarity you need. If you'd like, I can send you some clean examples and see if you can convert them to clean C++ code? "Find me another language that does anything approaching this power." --> Allow me to introduce D. :)

Comment: @wilhelmtell: Here's a **challenge** C++ problem: Do you think that you could write a function called `memoize()` in C++ or C++0x, that would take in the address of a function, and return another function with the *same exact signature* but one that cache the results of calling the original function, in perhaps a hash table? Note: you **may not** use varargs, because those are type-unsafe and unchecked by the compiler; the returned function (or function pointer) must have the exact same parameter list, no more, no less. I did this rather easily in D.

Comment: @Lambert: I'm in the D camp here, but you can do that in C++0x using variadic templates and rvalue references for perfect forwarding. I haven't thought it through entirely, but it seems like it would be possible.

Comment: @Peter: Interesting... but would the code turn out to be reasonably clean and readable? (Note that you can't put any bounds on the number of arguments, so you'd have to get a reference to every argument by an index.)

Comment: Two points: As far as I know, D doesn't attempt to *fix* c++ but rather conceded that it is an evolutionary dead end (that is that it can't be improved in ways that the creator of D wanted while still claiming much in the way of a C++ ancestry) and started over. It may well be closer to C than C++. -- And second: D's templates are able to do everything *I've* ever heard of C++'s doing and can do it in a way that most competent programmers can understand.

Comment: @Lambert: Yeah, it should be readable. No need for bounds, or array indexing; you would just unpack the template parameter packs right into the function call.

Comment: All right, let's do a little comparison. I wrote this piece of code that I talked about in just 36 lines: https://gist.github.com/741782#file_memoize.d
@Peter: Do you really think C++ would even come close to this, in either conciseness and/or readability?
@wilhelmtell: Just *try* doing this in C++. I suggest you look at the D code too, and please answer me honestly: is it more readable than the C++ version, or less? :)

Comment: @Lambert: Done http://ideone.com/g95Sc - Honestly, I think the C++0x version is tidier.

Comment: @Peter: I have to say, you (and C++) did very well; I honestly didn't expect this; +1. But I'm having a little trouble with something: You didn't return a function, you returned a function object (struct) -- and if you were to pass a memoized function to outside code, wouldn't it be a breaking change from the non-memoized version? Or am I missing something (which might very well be the case)? (The point of returning a lambda was so that you could pass it around just like the original function -- and a struct can't do that... or can it?)

Comment: @Lambert: You could easily just change the `memo` function to do what you ask (have it just hold a static version of the object, and do everything through that).

Comment: Huh... it seems to make sense... if you make `memo` hold a static object, you'd have to initialize it. But it's not like every version of `memo` belongs to one function, so you'd have to have a static map inside memo, then index it with the address of the user's function... correct? Hm... it seems reasonable, I'm trying to see how big of a change it is. Overall, I'll say I lost this, if for nothing else than not having tried this myself beforehand before passing judgments on C++. Thanks a lot for taking the time to type this!! :)

Comment: @Peter: Oh, and by the way, that's a pretty cool site you used, thanks for sharing! (On a side note, putting my [code](http://ideone.com/yjSSx) on there does make it look nicer. ;) )

Comment: @Lambert: The static variables would be unique per template instantiation of the function, so you just need to add the function as a template type parameter.

Comment: @Peter: But each template instantiation doesn't correspond to a memoized function -- two functions with the same signature would then share the same tables, which isn't what you want. So you'd have to index by the address inside another map, no?

Comment: @Lambert: Oh... yeah I'm not thinking today. Yes, you're right -- something along those lines.

Comment: (Don't worry, I wasn't thinking well either when I judged C++0x too early. ;) )
Yeah, it would make the code a little less pretty, I was just trying to figure out by how much. But it seems like you'd just need another `map<Func, Memoize<Func> >` in there (if this was before C++0x, that space would've been crucial!), and so that's pretty much the same, so yeah, I'd say it'd still look rather readable.

Comment: @Peter: Now I'm wondering about something else: What about compile-time function evaluation and mixins? Can you generate a string and then parse its contents as code in C++0x? (I really don't know this, I'm just asking -- since it's a really powerful feature that sometimes comes in very handy, and since it's not one I've heard C++ to have.)

Comment: @Lambert: C++ has no compile time function evaluation at all. In C++0x it has a very limited form, but nothing compared to D, and nothing like mixins.

Comment: @Peter: So D *is* more powerful than C++!!!

Comment: @Peter, @wilhelmtell: You know, at first I gave up and said C++0x is just as good as D, but now I take it back again: Would you please look at [this version of memoize() (20 lines)](http://ideone.com/lAzZQ)? What do you think? Can C++0x beat the readability and conciseness this time? (I'm really curious to know what you think now! :] )

Comment: There are plenty of things to fix in C++. The problem is that to do so, you have to sacrifice other things (backwards compatibility with either C or C++, runtime performance, compilation time or a number of other things). The only reason why D seems cleaner than C++ is because they were willing to throw away some of C++'s advantages, and focus more narrowly on the remaining ones.

Comment: And I think most people with only a glancing familiarity of D would agree that D usually wins out on readability and conciseness. But as already mentioned, it is no longer really competing with C++. It's wandered into a field where C# and other languages are much closer competitors. So that's really what it should be compared against. It is no longer a suitable substitute in a project that's currently using C++.

Comment: @jalf: What makes you say that? D occupies the same space as C++, i.e. systems programming and high performance computing. That is not what C# is used for.

Comment: No, C++ occupies the space in which compatibility with C and C++ is important, where mature, stable tool support is important, and where library support is near ubiquitous. D throws those things away, creating a new ecosystem from scratch. And if we're willing to do that, then we might as well switch to any of dozens other candidate languages. We're no longer required to stay anywhere within the C family of languages.

Comment: For a variety of reasons, systems programming is generally done in C or C++, whether or not D would, in a perfect world, be a better language for it. And high performance computing is done in practically any language, up to and including Python.

Comment: @jalf: "We might as well switch to any of dozens other candidate languages." --> I'm curious to know some examples of better languages for systems programming than D (and reasons why). Also, the main reason C/C++ are still used is legacy code -- and that's mainly only an issue with C++, because of incompatible ABI's. But I'd like to know *exactly* *which part* of D you believe makes it unsuitable for systems programming? You're making assertions such as "you can't compare D to C++" without any factual support.

Comment: @Peter, @wilhelmtell: Sorry for beating this to death, but since I came this far, I might as well put the link here: [Here's a 7-line version, still-completely-readable version of memoize()](http://ideone.com/UXPqO). Let's see how C++ compares. :)

Comment: @Lambert: I suspected there would be a nicer D version :-)  I don't think C++0x will be able to beat that.

Comment: @Lambert: I assumed it was clear that when I say "GC'ed languages", I mean "languages where you actually use the GC". If you use D without relying on the GC, then obviously characteristics of a GC'ed language do not affect you.

Comment: @jalf: D is compatible with C for the most part. All you need are the headers, which you can generate using an automated tool called htod. No need to generate libraries from scratch. Also, Python is *not* used for high performance computing. For example, you will *never* see a cutting edge rendering engine written in Python. It simply doesn't have what it takes.

Comment: @Lambert: I didn't say there were dozens of better systems programming languages. For systems programming, C and C++ are undisputed kings, not because of the languages themselves, but because they're established, widely used and widely supported. The thing that makes D unsuitable for systems programming is simply that "it is not commonly used for systems programming". If I used C++, I could work with the existing codebase I've been working on for the last 15 years, and I could use the thousands of libraries developed for it. With D...? Not so much.

Comment: @Peter: **every** language can use C libraries. That's not impressive, and it doesn't give D any kind of exclusive advantage. And yes, Python is used for HPC. A rendering engine is not typically considered HPC though; something running on a grid with a few thousand processors would be considered HPC, and Python is used there, believe it or not. And you know, I've never seen a cutting edge rendering engine implemented in D either. But I've seen several in C++. What does that tell you?

Comment: The thing D fans have trouble accepting is that *it's not really about the language*. Having a nice clean and well-designed language doesn't really buy you anything. You don't need to learn more than a couple of languages to realize that. As a general rule of thumb, the languages that end up getting popular are the ugly, clumsy and primitive ones. It doesn't *matter* that D has a cleaner syntax than C++, it doesn't matter that you can write an elegant memoization function, or a compile-time raytracer in it. It still doesn't have the *practical* qualities that make C and C++ stick around...

Comment: ... specifically, it doesn't have C/C++'s tool support, ubiquitous compilers, and source compatibility with existing code bases or libraries. It also doesn't have the millions of existing programmers familiar with the language, and it doesn't present a stable ecosystem (C/C++ being ISO certified might slow down the languages' evolution, but it also stabilizes it, making it less risky to use, because you know the language won't suddenly break your code next week). In the niche that C and C++ occupy, it's not really about elegance. If it was, C++ would've never caught on in the first place.

Comment: @jalf, Re: Rendering engine in D http://h3.gd/code/nucleus/ (says he uses D in the comments). Btw I wasn't saying that being able to use C libraries gave it an advantage, I was just refuting your claim that D programmers had to throw away C libraries and start a new ecosystem from scratch. It's just plain false.

Comment: @jalf: We realise that, which is why people are working to improve the toolchain and libraries.

Comment: @Peter: it wasn't about "a rendering engine". Those exist in Python too. It was about "a cutting edge rendering engine". And yes, D can use C libraries, but they're not part of the D ecosystem. They're not source compatible, I can't modify them without having to leave my nice little D-world. And they're not as simple to use as a "real" D library would be. And of course, I'm just plain out of luck if I were to try using a C++ library.

Comment: And sure, the people working on improving those things realize it (in general, there are a lot of supremely clever people working on D, many of whom know perfectly well why the language hasn't yet caught on), which is nice. The people who say D is a better choice for the C/C++ niche *today* apparently don't realize it.

Comment: @jalf: That engine is cutting edge.

Comment: @jalf: So you're by definition implying that because D isn't popular, it won't become popular. Which, unfortunately, might be true. But I'm not talking about popularity, I'm talking about the usefulness of the language itself. (Note: useful doesn't necessarily mean dozens of features; it also includes things like readability.) In popularity C++ wins, but the discussion (or at least, *my point*) is on utility, not popularity.

Comment: ..about your comment on having to learn more than one language: I started programming in middle school with Logo. Then I learned Visual Basic from my dad, then moved to VB.NET and C# on my own; then I learned C++ by myself and Java in high school, and recently I became better at assembly. I learned PHP/MySQL for some competitions; we used Scheme in college, so I learned that too. Now I've learned D. So I've learned more than one language (and I've learned them quite *well*, many of them pretty much inside-out), and my honest opinion is that language *does* matter, even if just for readability.

Comment: ... or even if to avoid silly errors like that in `map<int, map<char*, int>>` that shouldn't even exist in a language anyway. I was only caught off guard by Peter's program because it was C++0x instead of C++, which doesn't officially exist yet anyway -- I *know* for a fact that you can't get even close to what I did in D with pure C++. So don't assume that when we talk about the good sides of D, we haven't seen other languages too -- we have, and in my case, I'd say I've written enough useful programs in other languages (e.g.: a SCSI-based CD burner in C#) to make an informed judgment. :)

Comment: ... and by the way, if "it's not really about the language", then why did the world even move on to C++ in the first place? Even Windows is written in C, so C should pretty much satisfy anything, right? Why bother moving to C++? Also: If you're uncomfortable leaving the nice D bubble when interoperating with C/C++, I'd say you should really consider increasing your level of comfort; like you said, you can't be a good programmer in *any* single language, whether you're living in a comfortable C++ bubble or D bubble.

Comment: Nice to know that my response prompted so many comments.. most ever.

Comment: @Lambert: yep, that's pretty much what I'm saying (sad, but true. I'd love to live in a world where programming languages became popular based on their actual expressiveness and readability). And that the usefulness of the language *depends* on its popularity. A language that is in widespread use is inherently more useful than a small niche language, because of all the things you get "for free" in a popular language (better tools, more libraries, and a larger talent pool).

Comment: @Lambert: Windows is by and large written in C++. I'm not sure where you got the C thing from. (A hint is, of course, that virtually all Microsoft libs are C++, and that while the VC team is still heavily invested in improving C++ support, the C side of their compiler has been pretty much left to rot for the last decade). Anyway, the reason the world accepted C++ is that it was made easy. Because it was (especially in the early days) nearly 100% source compatible with C, the cost of adopting the language was near zero.

Comment: @Peter Alexander: How do you determine that? At a glance, I don't see anything in it that hasn't been done many times before. And of course, a feature-rich renderer can be (and has been) just as easily written in Python. Presumably the thing that'd make this superior would be performance. So how does it compare to all the big game engines written in C++?

Comment: @jalf: I thought that Windows was mostly in C? Because when you look at *most* DLLs (there's of course a few exceptions), you only see APIs with C linkages. Open up Explorer.exe in a disassembler... what makes you think it's C++ and not C?

Comment: @jalf: See [this link](http://discuss.fogcreek.com/joelonsoftware/default.asp?cmd=show&ixPost=28914) -- except for MFC and a few other examples, most Windows programs are still in C. (How many Windows programs do you see that depend on msvcrt.dll, and how many on msvcprt60.dll?) Looking at a disassembler, it even seems like ntoskrnl is written in C... what makes you think they're C++?

Comment: @Lambert: MS insist on keeping their APIs C-compatible.

Comment: Yeah, but what makes you think it's actually written in C++? (Why don't most DLL's depend on msvcprt**.dll? *Surely* MS wouldn't link things statically...)

Comment: @Lambert: There is no msvcprt.dll. I'm sitting looking at Visual Studio's CRT folder, and there's no msvcprt.

Comment: Sorry, typo on my part: the "-rt" doesn't exist, it's actually `msvcp60.dll`, and IIRC, it's always been in Windows since XP (it's not a redistributable, it's built in). So *surely* C++ programs would link to it?!

Comment: statements made by various Microsoft developers. Of course, Windows is a huge mess of different languages (I'm willing to bet you can still find some Pascal in there, along with C and C++ and, these days, C# and VB.NET). But they do use C++ widely. As @DeadMG says, they keep their APIs C-compatible because they know that the caller might not be using C++. And I see a lot of programs that depend on *various versions* of the C++ runtime lib. I don't know why you expect them to depend on the 12-year-old 6.0 runtime.

Comment: Of course it goes without saying that part of the kernel is going to be ASM and C. Anyway, "Most of the source code for Windows NT is written in C or C++" from http://technet.microsoft.com/sv-se/library/cc767881%28en-us%29.aspx. Doesn't say which language they use *most*, but my claim was just that C++ is a big part of Windows, just like C is.

Comment: Poking around with depends.exe, I'm having trouble finding an .exe or .dll which *doesn't* link to MFC. That tells me that 1) MFC, which is C++ code, is widely used in Windows, and 2) that the code that consumes it must be at least partly written in C++ as well, leading to the conclusion that there's a fair bit of C++ in Windows. Also, I can't believe we're even arguing about this. What difference does it make? Like I said, C++ got adopted because it offered an easy upgrade path. It didn't, and never will, replace C, but it got its place in the sun.

Answer (score 12):

C++0x is definitely more like D than C++ 98 or 03 is, but they're still definitely different languages. Stereotypically, D is viewed as a better C++, and it is more like C++ than any other language, but it's still very much its own beast. That being the case, the only feature that I can think of off the top of my head that C++ has which D definitely lacks is multiple inheritance, but given all of the problems with multiple inheritance, pretty much every language after C++ has decided against it. Instead, D introduces a number of other features such as `alias this` and mixins to allow for implementation inheritance (on top of having interfaces like C# and Java), so you can generally still get the benefits of multiple inheritance without all of the headaches. There are probably some other things that C++ has that D doesn't, but you're likely going to have to search hard for them.

D generally can do anything that C++ can do, but it can do more than C++ can, and it can often do it better. D's weaknesses lie primarily in its relatively young compiler implementation (which can mean bugs in the compiler when dealing with newer features) and the fact that its standard library is very much a work in progress (though much of what's there is fantastic, and it continues to improve and grow). However, given time, those problems will obviously go away. If anything, I'd say that D is quite a bit more powerful than C++. I find it frustrating when having to program in C++ after having done a bunch of programming in D. That's particulary true when it comes to templates (D's templates blow C++'s templates clear out of the water in terms of power and useability). Generally-speaking, D is just plain more powerful and less error-prone. The problems that it does have are implementation issues which are completely temporary and which are steadily being fixed.

Now, as for C++0x, it's adding a number of new features to C++ which are definitely going to improve it. Some of those features are already in D. Some examples of that would be lambdas, foreach loops, and `auto` (I'm particularly looking forward to `auto`. I've been quite suprised at how big a game changer it's been in D). So, some of the things that D improved on over C++ 98/03 are going to be in C++0x. But obviously not all of them will, and C++ is definitely a different language than D. It isn't D. It can't be D. And it shouldn't be D. While they are very similar at the core, they are definitely different languages.

If you really want to know more about D, you should check out Andrei Alexandrescu's [The D Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321635361), which is the definitive book on D and one of the best programming books that I've ever read. Also, as pointed out in another answer, there is a fairly good comparison grid of various languages [here](http://www.prowiki.org/wiki4d/wiki.cgi?LanguagesVersusD). And, of course, there's the [official site](http://www.d-programming-language.org).

Comment: Really any question regarding D can be answered with "please read the book".   Not only is Andrei's book a pleasant read but it's very informative, and well structured to cherry picking.  You won't regret it, even if you never end up using D.  Andrei does a great job explaining why you would want D's features, which will help anyone turn a critical eye to their own preferred language.

Answer (score 11):

I used to be a C# programmer (I know C++ and Java too), but after learning D, I'd say that it would be the best language ever, if only its compiler was bug-free. Just look at these pages:

[Languages versus D](http://www.prowiki.org/wiki4d/wiki.cgi?LanguagesVersusD)

[D Language Features](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/comparison.html)

There's two main reasons D hasn't caught on:

1. The compiler isn't bug-free <strike>(e.g. forward-reference errors are very annoying and a pain to solve)</strike> (Edit: it's improved a lot!).
2. There's no portable way to interact with legacy C++ code with pretty much any other language, including D. Hence most people are just forced to continue using C++ to be able to use their old code.
3. While using the GC isn't "required", the standard library uses it extensively, so you're pretty much forced to use it if you're using Phobos. There are plans to fix this, I think, but as long as this is the case, people who want manual memory management will probably avoid D.

If those problems were solved, I'd say that D would probably catch on pretty rapidly.

Comment: The you should try Felix. It's based on ML, was designed to bind to C++ from the start, and generates ISO C++ as its target language. The compiler surely isn't bug free, but you don't have to worry about forward references (lookup is set-wise like goto labels in C).

Comment: Huh, I'll look at it when I get the chance, thanks! :)

Comment: D will not catch on: it vests too much in Object Orientation which is the wrong answer. Look at the C++ standard library. Functional programming is the future, OO is a minor technique.

Comment: Haha at first I was going to disagree, but I totally agree that functional programming is the future, and that OOP is a technique (I'm not sure about the "minor" part though). But I'm curious, in what way is the C++ library more suited for functional programming than D's?

Comment: @Yttrill, D does have robust OOP features, why is this bad? The standard library does not make heavy use of objects and contains mostly free functions or structures. On of the best modules is std.algorithms http://digitalmars.com/d/2.0/phobos/std_algorithm.html which is influenced by the STL.

Comment: @Yttrill The designers of D completely understand the power of functional programming, and the standard library contains a lot of tools to that effect. The language has a type system that heavily emphasizes the power of immutable data, and a keyword to denote functions as pure so that the compiler can optimize more aggressively.

Comment: I know this is a D thread but "no portable way to interact with legacy C++ code with pretty much any other language" is worth addressing. With the introduction of [CXXI](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2011/Dec-19.html) (pronounced sexy), any .NET/Mono language can interop with and extend legacy C++ very cleanly

Answer (score 4):

D is a different language, supposedly invented to solve a lot of issues with C++.  I've never tried it because I wasn't ever bothered by C++'s "issues".

C++0x is a new standard for C++ that adds a lot of much needed features (not all we'd hoped for unfortunately though).  To see what C++0x adds, have a look at the wiki entry on it:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x

Comment: This is meant as an honest question and not a troll. If you were not ever bothered by C++'s "issues" then why do you think that the new C++0x features are "much needed". Is it that the new features made you recognize the problems you were having or is it that you saw the problems already and just do not mind that the language is broken in some ways?

Answer (score 4):

C++0x is the next standard of C++ (the previous of which was set in 2003). The two are one single language.

D is a whole other language. You might better ask what are the commonalities between C++ and D. I have approximately zero experience with D so I can't tell you my view on it, but I do have quite a bit of experience with C++. I've heard that one of the most significant (supposed) issues with C++ that D solves is garbage collection: C++ doesn't have a garbage collector while D does have one.

I personally like it C++'s way much better. I know little about garbage collectors, but last time I checked there was no efficient garbage collector in existence which guarantees correct and deterministic memory clean-up, with regard to exactly when the GC bursts in and does its stuff. Granted, dynamic allocation in C++ can fail, but there are ways to group all of the program's memory allocation failures to one point (a memory pool), such that you can tell at compile-time that once you pass that point there shall be no failures by `operator new`. This technique also gives you nearly-instant dynamic allocations: allocations are then internal to the program and are a mere game of pointers.

Also, garbage collectors only apply for memory, not other resources.

Comment: If you don't know much about GC why comment? Modern GC is generational and incremental, and some can even run concurrently, and programs in high level languages are generally faster and jitter free. If C is a "portable assembler" then C++ is an assembler with an ugly macro processor thrown on top. :)

Comment: @Yttrill What I meant is that the garbage collector decides when to come in, and it does so in mostly unpredictable times. Here I expect people with good GC knowledge to correct me if I'm wrong. If my code relies on performance, how can I be sure that the garbage collector won't come in at a specific period? For example, if I land an airplane it's going to be a very bad timing to release memory. Also, the preprocessor comes from C, not C++.

Comment: @wilhelmtell, he said macro processor (responsible for the sad excuse for an object system in C++), not the preprocessor. Also, modern garbage collectors are very different from early garbage collectors, which gained a pretty unfair reputation for always trying to reclaim memory at the precise wrong instant. Modern GCs don't really "burst in" like the Kool-Aid man and wreck your real-time systems.

Comment: @wilhelmtell, D allows you to turn the GC off, preventing collections. You can still use the same manual memory management techniques used in C++.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: -1 -- not because I disagree, but because of incorrect information: **ALL** dynamic memory allocation is non-deterministic. (Ever heard of `malloc()` guaranteeing to respond in 5 ms real-time, for instance?) The GC doesn't change that. I *really* suggest you see this page to see why the GC is useful: http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/garbage.html
(As he_the_great said, though, you can always turn it off if you really want to.)

Comment: @Lambert I'll take a more serious look at D later. A bit busy now. But per your downvote: there's a difference between new and a GC. I control new, and I don't control GC. I can use a memory pool for one thing, and then new **is** deterministic to respond fast and to **work**. That is, forward all the program's memory failures to the beginning of its run. I can play with that. Also: I like RAII.

Comment: @Lambert I will look at D more closely, but make sure you don't downvote me in defending a language. Did I really say something **wrong**? I didn't say a word about new or malloc. Did I say something wrong about GC?

Comment: @wilhelmtell: I downvoted because it clearly implied that user-allocated memory (aka non-GC'ed memory) is deterministic, which is false. But given that you didn't technically say this (even though it was very *clearly* implied), I'll remove my down vote (and change it to +1, since it's otherwise a great answer) if you make a slight change so as to not imply that. (I can't change it now anyway because it's locked in... sorry about this. :( )

Comment: @wilhelmtell: As a side note, you *are* able to control the GC in D. You can disable it and, if I'm not mistake, you can overload `new` and `delete` just like in C++. So you have pretty much as much control as you want.

Comment: @Lambert clarified my point. I'm still defensive with C++ :) because I still need to dig into D.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: Thanks for the clarification; +1 (or +2 if you look at it very optimistically haha). :)
And I realized I'm kind of the opposite of you... I knew a fair amount of C++ and after learning D I learned all about its mistakes, but now I need to dig into C++0x (as opposed to D for you) before prejudging it based on its predecessor. And thanks for the discussions (here and below), I learned a lot. :)

Comment: D supports scope-based destruction in a manner similar to C++, as well as through the language's `scope` keyword, which means that non-memory resources can be cleaned up just as efficiently as in the latter.

Comment: @Lambert: "deterministic" in this context usually means that you can control the *order* in which things happen, not that you know the precise duration of a function call. C++ is deterministic in this respect. new/delete/free/malloc are called in a known order. Destructors are called at known points in the program. That is not the case in GC'ed languages.

Comment: @jalf: "That is not the case in GC'ed languages." I'm not sure if you've used D, but it allows you to delete objects manually. So destructors can be called at known points in GC'ed programs, too.

Answer (score 2):

Just trying to provide a simple summary answer:

**C++**
is an imperative, multi-paradigm programming language. C++ until recently provided no primitives for concurrency, and programmers relied heavily on library support.  C++ supports complex multiple inheritance. The C++ standard includes an extensive standard library.

**C++0x**
As of writing (2-Jan-2011) C++0x is the latest draft standard of C++.  It adds many new features that help to bring it inline with other modern languages. Some of the more notable features include: concurrency and threading features, lambda expressions and extensions the existing meta-programming support.

**D** is a separate language heavily influenced by C++. It borrows concepts from Java and Eiffel.  D implements garbage collection. D has replaced C++ multiple inheritance with interfaces and mix-ins support.

C++ and D have completely different standard library implementations.
C++ has gained wide industry acceptance and is commonly used.  D has failed to penetrate the industry to the same degree.